# What does "->" mean in a C++ template declaration? (Not the object pointer member access.)

Tags: c++, c++11

The cppreference.com shows the following snippet at the very bottom of [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/array):

```
template<class T, class... U>
array(T, U...) -> array<T, 1 + sizeof...(U)>;
```

I've never seen this syntax, so I wonder:

1. What does it mean?
2. Was it introduced in a rather recent standard?

Comment: Yes, the question is answered in the other thread. But I'll never understand why that leads to a downvote. It's obviously not possible to find the answer by searching.

Comment: There's a page on the same reference dedicated to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides